# Convert rgb number array to hexadecimal color string

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex, rgb, converters

I have already written a working method, that can convert an array of rgb values to a hexadecimal color string:

```js
/**
 * @param {Number[]} arr Array with three entries (rgb: [0-255, 0-255, 0-255]).
 * @return {String} Hex color as a string (rgb: '#000000' - '#ffffff').
 */
function arrToHex(arr) {
  return '#' + arr
    .map(v => ('0' + v.toString(16)).slice(-2))
    .join('');
}
```

But I'm unsure whether this method is the best approach when it comes to efficiency. This method is called pretty often in my code.

Especially the part with `('0' + v.toString(16)).slice(-2)` (to get a double hexadecimal) seems too complicated to me. Can this be done better? Is this [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach even the best?

---

## Performance evaluations:

Results show average seconds calculated by [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) if run with Google Chrome v83 (64bit, Linux).
Ordered from best to worst.

#### Iterative and lookup table solution by [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458):  (~1.1sec)

```js
const hextable = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
function arrToHex(arr) {
  let s = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    s += hextable[(arr[i] / 16) | 0];
    s += hextable[arr[i] % 16 | 0];
  }
  return s;
}

console.time('arrToHex');
for (var r = 0; r < 256; r++)
for (var g = 0; g < 256; g++)
for (var b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
  arrToHex([r, g, b]);
}
console.timeEnd('arrToHex');
```

#### Iterative and no lookup table solution by [selbie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104458): (~1.8sec)

```js
function arrToHex(arr) {
  let s = '#';
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    s += ((arr[i] / 16) | 0).toString(16);
    s += ((arr[i] % 16) | 0).toString(16);
  }
  return s;
}
console.time('arrToHex');
for (var r = 0; r < 256; r++)
for (var g = 0; g < 256; g++)
for (var b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
  arrToHex([r, g, b]);
}
console.timeEnd('arrToHex');
```

#### Non-iterative solution by [deleted]: (~2.6sec)

```js
function arrToHex(arr) {
  const rgb = arr[2] | (arr[1] << 8) | (arr[0] << 16);
  return '#' + rgb.toString(16).padStart(6, '0');
}

console.time('arrToHex');
for (var r = 0; r < 256; r++)
for (var g = 0; g < 256; g++)
for (var b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
  arrToHex([r, g, b]);
}
console.timeEnd('arrToHex');
```

#### My bad [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) approach: (~6.5sec)

```js
function arrToHex(arr) {
  return '#' + arr
    .map(v => ('0' + v.toString(16)).slice(-2))
    .join('');
}

console.time('arrToHex');
for (var r = 0; r < 256; r++)
for (var g = 0; g < 256; g++)
for (var b = 0; b < 256; b++) {
  arrToHex([r, g, b]);
}
console.timeEnd('arrToHex');
```

Comment: `.toString(16).padStart(2,'0')` is another way around to make sure you have 2 hex-digits, other than that, your code looks pretty viable

Comment: Given that browsers can do the conversion all by themselves, since each of the following are valid colours in css: `#rgb` or `#rrggbb` or `#rrggbbaa` or `rgb(r,g,b)` or `rgba(r,g,b,a)`, and that the conversion will be done by native code, rather than javascript, is there any real reason to do the conversion at all? Without knowing more, I wouldn't discount simplifying this whole method to the roughly equivalent: `reurn( 'rgb(' +r+ ',' +g+ ',' +b+ ')' );`

Comment: @enhzflep I already know the `rgb` function in CSS, but this isn't helpful in my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try benchmarking this code:

```
const hextable = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

function arrToHex(arr) {
    let s = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        s += hextable[(arr[i] / 16) | 0];
        s += hextable[arr[i] % 16 | 0];
    }
    return s;
}
```

Or as discussed in the comments, to avoid the table lookup and rely on the runtime to do the mapping:

```
function arrToHex(arr) {
    let s = '#';
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        s += ((arr[i] / 16) | 0).toString(16);
        s += ((arr[i] % 16) | 0).toString(16);
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Neat, but the `Math.floor` functions can be reduced: `Math.floor(arr[i] / 16)` to `arr[i] / 16 | 0` and `Math.floor(arr[i] % 16)` to just `arr[i] % 16`

Comment: That's a neat idea.  I've made it `arr[i]%16|0` so it can reasonably support decimal numbers as well.  It doesn't handle negative or out of range values perfectly. That's an exercise for the OP (you) to consider.

Comment: Why not `hextable = [...'0123456789abcdef']` and `hextable[0|arr[i]/16]`? (the second may somewhat increase the performance, by the way)

Comment: The JS doc defines that is allowed to be given to the function, everything else doesn't bother me.

Comment: |@selbie @YevgenGorbunkov I'll do a performance analysis and edit my answer to provide the results. Give me a moment...

Comment: Congrats. I wasn't right with the lookup vs. `toString(16)`, but I was right with the `Math.floor` vs `|` floor. I tested the Math.floor solution with 1.3sec, which is >10% runtime increase! (test not included in the question edit)